# Adding another value in Excel cell/column if another cell has particular value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I wanted to be able to create a macro to change the value in Cell B to `EPTBSIET` if it equaled that value in Cell E - `SIETCO`. I've been able to compile an `IF` formula but would rather have the value not written into another cell. Any suggestion?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("SIETCO",E2)),"EPTBSIET","")
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. What are you actually asking for? You have a working formula. It would also help if you include visuals if your questions is harder to understand

Comment: @CallumDS33 I'm asking to change the value of one cell if another cell is of a certain value. The formula above works but i want to embed a macro into the spreadsheet without having to put a formula in another cell. Will try to upload pics when possible

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following VBA code to change an imputted value that countains "SIETCO", to "EBTBSIET" over the range **A1:A10**. You should be able to easily adapt this to your need.

In the code editor, you need to add this code to the sheet you wish to use it on, rather than a module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Target.Find("SIETCO", LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Value = "EBTBSIET"
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx